# Unable to load the Chart Data via AJAX

Tags: solspace, solspace-tracker

I just installed the [Solspace Tracker](http://www.solspace.com/software/detail/tracker/) module in my ExpressionEngine installation (v2.7.0), and I am getting the following error on my publish page:

> Unable to load the Chart Data via AJAX

I have deleted and reinstalled the themes folder, but I am still getting this error.  Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: As of this writing, Solspace add-ons are not yet fully EE 2.7-compatible. See our blog post for more info: http://www.solspace.com/blog/entry/compatibility_with_ee_2.7.0/

Comment: Great to know.  Thanks so much for the reply.  I'll be awaiting the 9th!

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Can you give me an update if this issue has been solved?

I get "Unable to load the Chart Data via AJAX" in EE CMS as well when trying to get tracking information older than 3 months. My client wants to see "Most read articles this year" but it tracks down to 3 months ago.

Best regards,

Harold Kuiper